# django model add category to object

Tags: python, django, web

```
class Venues(models.Model):
        ..........
        ..........
        category=models.ForeignKey(Category)


class Category(models.Model):
     club=models.CharField()
     bar=models.CharField()
     adult=models.CharField()
```

These are the models that I have. I am a django newbie so please pardon this rather simple question. I want every Venue object to have one category that is selected from the list of categories(i.e club,bar or adult). So each category--club,bar,adult--can have many Venues but like I said every Venue has one category.

So am i at all close to what im trying to accomplish or is this totally wrong?? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Category` could have a one field called `type` that type could be a string either 'club', 'bar', 'adult'.  Also you could just have a Venue with a char field and give it a set of fixed [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices).  So as you see there are already a couple of ways to approach the way you set up your database.  Can venues have more than one category? If so you might want to use a [manytomany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) field. 
I think one of the issues is right now if you wanted to add a new category you would have to manually add it in the code.  If you chose a gave `Category` just a type field a user could add new categories from the admin without changing any code.

if you're wondering how to actually add a category to a Venue you first need to get a category instance. This can be done by retrieving one already in your db or createing a new one

```
category = Category.objects.get(pk=1)
```

next you can just create a new Venue using that category

```
new_venue = Venue(category=category, other_args)
new_venue.save()
```

will save a new venue with the category.  Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs) provides a great reference.

Comment: Ok thank you this was a perfect solution. I added a set of fixed choices to a model field named category, as I only needed 3 fixed choices. Now how would I call those objects or filter the objects by the choice chosen?